# How to use image inside a div without moving the other elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex-box and I'm trying to make my website responsive. Right now I need to put an image inside the yellow divs but when I do that all the structure changes cause of that. I trying playing around with the width and height but could make that work. Hope one of you could help me out

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #0077be;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.screen {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section-title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.news-conainer {
  flex-grow: 11;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 17px;
}

.main-news {
  flex-grow: 11;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.foot-news {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-news {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.left-news:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.left-news-img {
  flex-grow: 1.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.left-news-info {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section-title">title</div>
        <div class="news-conainer">
          <div class="main-news">
            <div class="right">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="./new1.JPG" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="info">info</div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="./new1.JPG" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="./new1.JPG" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="./new1.JPG" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="foot-news"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The result I need is at the yellow divs to include a < img > tag  without destroying the other sizes and their positions

Thanks!

[image]

result by adding

```
.left-news-img {
max-width: 30%;
}
.left-news-img > img {
  max-width: 100%;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `max-width`

```
.left-news-img {
    max-width: 30%;
}
.left-news-img > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #0077be;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.screen {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section-title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.news-conainer {
  flex-grow: 11;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 17px;
}

.main-news {
  flex-grow: 11;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.foot-news {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-news {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.left-news:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.left-news-img {
  flex-grow: 1.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.left-news-info {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.left-news-img {
    max-width: 30%;
}
.left-news-img > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.right > .img{
   max-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section-title">title</div>
        <div class="news-conainer">
          <div class="main-news">
            <div class="right">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x130" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="info">info</div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x130" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x130" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-news">
                <div class="left-news-img">
                <img src="./new1.JPG" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-info"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="foot-news"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Update**

for your right section you have to provide some `max-width` like

```
.right > .img{
   max-width: 30%;
}
```

and get rid of `height: 100%` from `.img img` selector, check above demo as I have update the code there

Comment: im afraid that not good i upload an image at the top of your solution @Rahul

Comment: Still the div is only half full with the image. the other half is empty with the yellow background @Rahul

Comment: have you check my demo ? you find same issue there ?

Comment: yes and its working when there are 3 elements only for few you see only half div full with image...